# PHP Convert string datetime in UTC into GMT+7 format

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, date-formatting

i have a datetime string in `Y-m-d H:i:s` UTC format, i want to convert this string to `Y-m-d H:i:s` GMT+7 format, for example:

```
$utcDateTime = '2018-10-02 04:08:17';
$gmtDateTime = $this->convertDateTime($utcDateTime);
echo $gmtDateTime; // 2018-10-02 11:01:02
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this. And this is php [timezone](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php).

```
function convertDateTime($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $tz1 = 'UTC';
    $tz2 = 'Antarctica/Davis'; // UTC +7

    $d = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone($tz1));
    $d->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($tz2));

    return $d->format($format);
}

$utcDateTime = '2018-10-02 04:08:17';

echo convertDateTime($utcDateTime); // 2018-10-02 11:08:17
```